# Can python packages be downloaded with dependencies when neither python and pip are available?

Tags: python, package, pypi

I'm in a situation, where I have internet access on a computer but do not have permisson to install anything and python is missing as well.

Python on the other hand is installed on another computer without internet access. Both are in separate networks but i can transfer files through a file server which is connected to each computer as a networkn drive.

---

My quesion is, if it is possible to download packages with all the dependencies without having python and pip installed, than transfer the file and finally install it.

I simply tried to install a downloaded package from the PyPi Website as a *.zip or *.tar.gz file using the cmd  with

```
chdir \path\to\package\file
python setup.py install
```

Importing that package afterwards creates errors as the dependencies are  missing.

---

It would be totally fine if I just download Anaconda as all needed packages are already included with the installation. But I would still have the same problem when I want to update the packages.

Comment: depending on the machine, you could run pyinstaller, which would package the Python as an executable file..  There are various ways to compile Python down to Bytecode.

Comment: How can pyinstaller help me in my case? I don't have the permission to install anything on the machine which has internet access.

Comment: Is there maybe a website where I could run pip just as I would do within cmd? Than I could run `pip download SomePackage` and in the process it will download it to my machine.

Comment: i dont think you really understand how python works.  Firstly, you need a Runtime env.  This is typically by having it installed onthe machine.  IF you need to run it on the machine, you would need the runtime.  If you do not have access to the runtime, you CAN convert it into pure bytecode on another machine by pyinstaller or some other tools (if it is a windows machine) and then use CURL or reference it by an internet to download the bytecode which can be run.  BUT it would still require it to be downloaded and then executed.